# How can I have dependencies installed automatically when using Module::Build::Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, build, perl-module, mojolicious, mojo

I'm trying to package up a [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) App I wrote and have been following the instructions with  [Mojolicious::Plugin::InstallablePaths](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious).

My `Build.PL` looks something like this;

```
use Module::Build::Mojolicious clean_install => 1;
my $builder = Module::Build::Mojolicious->new(
module_name => 'test',
dist_author => 'me,
license => 'perl',
configure_requires => {
  'Module::Build::Mojolicious' => 0,
  'Module::Build' => 0.38,
},
requires => {
                'File::Find::Rule' => 0,
                'File::MMagic' => 0,
                'Mojolicious' => 0,
                'Mojolicious::Plugin::Authorization' => 0,
                'Crypt::Blowfish' => 0,
                'Experimental' => 0,
            },

share_dir => 'lib/Jacaranda/files',
);

$builder->create_build_script;
```

My question is how do I get the dependencies to run the script, namely `Module::Build::Mojolicious` installed without having to install them from CPAN manually?

I don't want people who want to install my application to have to install these dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

Like any Perl module, you should just be able to tell the cpan client to install the dependencies. I recommend using [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm), using it is as simple as

```
$ cpanm --instaldeps .
```